# Recovering from a concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, java-8

So I'm stuck with a thread hostile singleton implementation that returns an Iterator to a HashSet.
I have two threads that -sometimes- access this Iterator simultaneously to load data. I'll call them the luckyThread and the unluckyThread.
*ONE* of them (unluckyThread) throws a ConcurrentModificationException.

Question: Is is safe to assume all is well with the other thread?
To be specific: is the data loaded by the luckyThread free of corruption?
(The couple of time this happened the system chugged along just fine, except for the unluckyThread)
Don't think this question requires any code sample, but I'd be happy to provide them if required.

Update: (without getting into details) the system is fine as long as one of the threads loads a clean data set. And quite needless to say I fixed this issue, but this got me thinking about recovering from such exceptions and I did not find anything concrete online.

Comment: No it is not at all safe to live on assumptions , you never know which thread is lucky and unlucky , better prefer Syncrhonized access.

Comment: Can't you fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), it clearly states that:

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally
>   speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of
>   unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it
>   would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for
>   its correctness: *ConcurrentModificationException should be used only
>   to detect bugs.*

Instead, you probably should use some other mechanism to make sure there's no concurrent access (like using using a `synchronized`-block with the singleton while accessing the underlying HashSet).

Comment: That won`t fix his problem with multiple threads accessing the returned iterator.  That code just needs to be refactored to not do this.

Comment: @Robin: fair enough, I probably should have said something along the lines of "using synchronized block with the singleton while accessing the underlying HashSet"... At least in the case of HashSet, it actually returns a *new* iterator on each iterator() -call, so the threads are not sharing the same iterator, but of course it is still NOT safe to use them concurrently, if either of them or something else can cause the underlying collection to change.

Comment: "Could be safe" is saddly not true. Worst case is an infinite loop on the iteration if there is a change to the underlying set. YOu might get lucky, but definitly not safe.

Comment: @Guillaume: True, I removed the first sentence

Answer (score 3):

The exception is thrown because the backing store has changed, which makes any usage of an iterator on that store vulnerable to the exception.  This can even occur in a single threaded application if poorly written.  In your case, neither of your threads is overly lucky because both can suffer this exception when the change occurs.

Even without a change to your underlying HashSet, having two threads access your iterator can lead to indeterminate behaviour since both will change the internal state of the iterator, not to mention that in the best case scenario each thread will be grabbing different items from your set.

The code is not safe as is and has to be rewritten to use a threadsafe Set and to NOT share the iterator between threads.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely unsafe. You are at the moment seeing the best case scenario : one thread gets a `ConcurrentModificationException`. It could be much worse than this. Behaviour of a `HashSet` is undefined under concurrent access. I'm not sure how stable an iterator on a `HashSet` is, but a quick look to the sources let me think that it could go very wrong. In case the keys are rehashed during iteration, you have a good chance to end up in an infinite loop.

Conclusion: either synchronize the access to the iterator, create a copy of your set (in a synchronized block) or change to a thread safe collection.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be to use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead of HashMap. You do not need to have synchronized blocks when accessing ConcurrentHashMap in multithreaded application.

Comment: You still can`t share the Iterator between threads.  It is safe for multiple threads to get their own iterator and use them, but not to share.

Comment: @Robin: agreed. In this case it won't suffice.